# jqplot to get  a horizontal line at 0 in bargraph

Tags: jquery

[image: image one i am getting but i need to get it as image 2. If you see the image2there is zero poini on a y axis which i need to get]i am using the jqplot to get a vertical bar graph, the values on my y-axis have both negative and positive numbers. The graph is displayed fine, but i want the coordinate (0,0) always displayed in the graph, so that i can  easily differentiate between the negative and the positive part of the bar. How is it possible.
Image1 i am getting it now from my code but i need to get it as image 2. If you see the image2 there is zero point on a y axis which i need to get

Answer (score 0):

Does setting "forceTickAt0" to true help to solve your problem?

See http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/axisScalingForceTickAt.html